# Is an init-declarator a prvalue expression

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

```cpp
int c = 0;
```

Consider the above code,thereof,`c = 0` is an init-declarator and it's also an expression,Becuase of these rules:

> init-declarator:
>   declarator initializer(opt)
>
> A full-expression is:
>   [...]
>   an **init-declarator** or a mem-initializer, including the constituent expressions of the initializer,

As long as an expression,it will have a value category.

> A prvalue is an expression **whose evaluation initializes an object** or a bit-field, or computes the value of the operand of an operator, as specified by the context in which it appears.

The evaluation of `a = 0` will initialize object `a`.So, Is the full-expression `c=0` a prvalue expression?If I misunderstand it,please correct me.

Comment: Being a full-expression doesn't mean that it is an expression, oddly enough.

Comment: @eerorika if a full-expression is not considered ,why there is something like `whose full-expression is a constant expression` in the standard?we know the prior condition for **constant expression** is it must be a **core constant expresion**

Comment: Some full-expressions are expressions. Not all.

Comment: @eerorika Could you please list some situation that full-expressions are expressions?or can be found in the standard?

Comment: @jackX Are there any situations where you are unclear what rules that applies? Those would be interesting to blend into the mix.

Comment: @jackX All expressions that are not sub expressions are full-expressions for example. For example in the expression statement `i++;`, the expression `i++` is a full-expression.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I just can't understand the distinction between `expression` and `full-expression`,in other words.The rules apply to **expression** can aslo apply to **full-expression**?

Comment: @jackX Only if the full-expression is an expression. And not all full-expressions are expressions.

Comment: @eerorika excatly.The full-expression `i++;` ,it's a prvalue expression.So why a arbitrary full-expression can't have a value category?Or,how to distinct which full-expression can't have a value category?

Comment: @eerorika how to determine whether a `full-expression` is also a **expression** or it just a **full-expression**?

Comment: @jackX It's not arbitrary. Expressions have a value category. `i++` is an expression, therefore it has a value category. `int i = 0;` is not an expression. Therefore it does not have a value category. Whether it is a full-expression is not is irrelevant.

Comment: @jackX See the standard section [expr] which defines all expressions. if it is not defined in the section, then it is not an expression. Or check [gram.expr] section for a list, although the grammar can be confusing at times.

Comment: @eerorika thanks.you mean that some rules in the standard that apply to **expression**,we can't apply the rule to **full-expression** arbitrarily,except that the **full-expression** is also a **expression**,Right?

Comment: If this is going to be worth anything (in the long run) - please put up an answer. For a non-theorist like me, following your discussion gets me nowhere. :-)

Comment: @jackX Yes. Rules that apply to expressions only apply to expressions. If something is not an expression, then rules applying to expressions do not apply to it. There are full-expressions that are not expressions. Therefore there are rules that apply to expressions which do not apply to all full-expressions.

Comment: @eerorika I see it,but how to interpret "the full-expression of the initialization shall be a constant expression",as I said,the **init-declarator** is only a full-expression,however,these rules in [expr.const] explicitly apply to **expression**,not to **full-expression**.

Comment: @jackX That, I don't know ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @eerorika Does it mean that all expressions within the full-expression must be constant expression?otherwise,there's no way to interpret this sentence,because as you said ,the rules in [expr.const] only apply to expression...

Comment: @jackX Perhaps. That would make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Consider the above code,thereof,c = 0 is an init-declarator and it's also an expression

That's not how C++ parsing works. `c = 0` by itself may be an expression (if it is within a context where expressions are allowed), but that's not how `int c = 0;` gets parsed. You have to follow the actual C++ grammar rules.

`int c = 0;` is a [*simple-declaration*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/gram.dcl), containing a *decl-specifier-seq* and an optional *init-declarator-list*. The latter is a sequence of one or more [*init-declarator*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/gram.decl) terms. And this grammar has two components: a *declarator* and an optional *initializer*. Grammatically speaking, the *decl-specifier-seq* is where `int` goes, the *declarator* is the `c` part, and the *initializer* is the `= 0` bit.

The text of an *init-declarator* is something that may in some cases be parsed as an *expression*. But what something is parsed as is determined by the *grammar rules*. And the grammar rules of *simple-declaration* does not allow a *decl-specifier-seq* followed by [*expression*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/gram.expr). Therefore, what follows it is not parsed as an *expression* even if it could be.

So *init-declarator* is not an *expression*, even if the text looks like it could be.

Now, there is the concept of a ["full-expression"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.execution#12). One of the things that get to be called a "full-expressions" are *init-declarator* grammar.

The part that's confusing you is the difference between a "full-expression" and an *expression*. An *expression* is a [specific piece of C++ grammar](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/gram.expr). A full-expression *is not*; it's a language concept which includes a number of different pieces of grammar, but full-expression is not itself grammar.

Therefore, while the grammatical construct *init-declarator* is a "full-expression" that *does not* make it an *expression*. The grammar construct *expression* is well defined, and `int c = 0;` doesn't fit that grammar. The *init-declarator* may *contain* an *expression* (or multiple expressions, depending on the *initializer*), but it is not itself an *expression*.

And only *expression*s have value categories. Therefore, asking about the value category of a thing which is not an *expression* is not a valid question.

Comment: I have to say that `int` within `int c = 0;` is a **decl-specifier-seq**,the part `c =0` within `int c = 0;` is a **init-declarator**,because [dcl.decl#nt:init-declarator](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.decl#nt:init-declarator)

Comment: For `int c = 0;`,it has three components,[dcl.decl#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.decl#2)

Comment: @jackX: I've fixed the references and the text, but the point remains; you don't get to say "hey, this grammar looks like an expression, so it is one". You have to follow C++'s grammar rules. "*it has three components*" Yes, and not one of those three components is, by itself, an expression. Some of them may contain expressions, but they're not "expression" as far as the C++ grammar is concerned.

Comment: Thanks for your answers,In short,you mean that these rules in the standart that apply to **expression**,we can't apply these rules to **full-expression** arbitrarily.Howerver,I have a confusion about the sentence "the full-expression of the initialization shall be a constant expression",we know these rules in [expr.const] apply to **expression**,so how to interpret this . A init-declarator is not an expression,how to determine whether it's a constant expression use these rules in [expr.const]?

Comment: (jack, put a space after a punctuation ... it's hard to read now)

Comment: @jackX: Your question here is about the value category of a "full-expression". Now you're asking a different question about a specific use of the "full-expression" concept in some case.

Comment: @NicolBolas  All right,I have to ask another question.Appreciate you to give an answers,I will give a link later  -:)

Comment: @jackX: If you ask another question, please use proper spacing around punctuation. IE: not *no spacing*.

Comment: @NicolBolas Hi, Nicol. Please give an answers for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62078530/how-to-understand-the-sentence-full-expression-must-be-a-constant-expression-w)

Comment: @jackX Your style is perfectly fine except for in that one comment.